# Move Subsite to Top Level Site

Tags: site-collection, sub-site

I have a user who, instead of editing the Top Level Site in their Site collection, created a subsite, named it "Home" and now wants this moved up a level so that it is their Site Collection Home Page.

Im sure there must be a simple way to do this that I am missing!

Answer (score 1):

Do not think it is possible to move the RootWeb of a Site Collection. In any other hierarchical level than root you can do it with "Manage Content and Structure" http://www.thesharepoint.com/SitePages/Content%20and%20Structure.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Back up, restore, or move a SharePoint site - How do I move a SharePoint site from one location to another?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/back-up-restore-or-move-a-sharepoint-site-HA010069939.aspx#_Toc266876707) claims that Sharepoint Designer can *save* a site, then *restore* it to another location. [Restore a Web site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/back-up-restore-or-move-a-sharepoint-site-HA010069939.aspx#_Toc266876710) section confirms it's possible to restore one as a top-level site.

Answer (score 0):

Try using - Save site as template.